# Get tr having specific th value from the table having an id using Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am using python3.6 with XPath library. Crawling inside the table gives me an empty list. And need to crawl to specific th.

My tr contents are dynamically generated. I need to crawl to tr which has a specific th value. Example In HTML code, the Rank appears in the second tr but it can appear in anywhere in tr. It doesn't have a specific index. Need to get the href from the tr having the Rank th.

My html file:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
            Product Number
         </th>
         <td class="a-size-base">
            B003NR57BY
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
             Rank
         </th>
         <td>
            <span>
            <span>#3 in <a href="/gp/bestsellers/pc/11036491/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_pc_1_1_last">Computer Mice</a></span>
            <br>
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">
            Created Date
         </th>
         <td class="a-size-base">
            June 7, 2010
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Python code:

```
listings_details = parser.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_DETAILS)
   for row in listings_details:
      th = row.xpath("./th/text()")
      if th[0].strip() == 'Rank':
         categories = row.xpath("./td/span/span//text()")
         qid_url= row.xpath("./td/span/span//@href")
```

I expect the output to be

```
Rank: 3,
url : /gp/bestsellers/pc/11036491/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_pc_1_1_last,
category: Computer Mice
```

Comment: In Python code the first line is missing     XPATH_PRODUCT_DETAILS = "//table[@id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1']"

Answer (score 2):

> Need to get the href from the tr having the Rank th.

Use:

```
/table/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th)='Rank']/td//a/@href
```

**Note**: this works for your provided fragment (**now well-formed**). You need to add later a context for selecting the `table` element.

```
<table> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Product Number</th>  
      <td class="a-size-base">B003NR57BY</td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr> 
      <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Rank</th>  
      <td> 
        <span> 
          <span>#3 in 
            <a href="/gp/bestsellers/pc/11036491/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_pc_1_1_last">Computer Mice</a>
          </span>  
          <br/> 
        </span> 
      </td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr> 
      <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">Created Date</th>  
      <td class="a-size-base">June 7, 2010</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Test in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/53808ee94dfbc5b38f12791cf857ffb9

Comment: My table contents:  `<table id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1" class="a-keyvalue prodDetTable" role="presentation">` . So are suggesting to `/table[@id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th)='Rank']/td//a/@href `

Comment: If `table` element might be at any depth then use `//table[@id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1']/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th)='Rank']/td//a/@href` provided that `id` attributes are unique.

Comment: @Roshan: Alejandro is showing you how to go straight to your target via XPath.  You can thus avoid iterating in python over the rows.

Comment: @kjhughes is right. I've quoted the specific question this is answering.

Comment: @kjhughes . Thank you clarifying

Comment: @Roshan: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.